# Почему текстовый файл(.txt) не открывается в окне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, файлы, pyqt5

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QAction, QPushButton, QWidget, QTabWidget, QFileDialog, QLabel,
                             QLineEdit, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QMessageBox, QTextEdit, QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Example'

        # Размеры окна приложения
        self.left = 20
        self.top = 50
        self.width = 1330
        self.height = 670
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button_1 = QPushButton('Bt', self)
        button_1.resize(50, 50)
        button_1.move(100, 100)
        button_1.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        text = QTextEdit(self)
        text.resize(300, 400)
        text.move(160,160)

        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/')[0]
        try:
            f = open(fname, 'r')
            with f:
                data = f.read()
                self.textEdit.setText(data)
                f.close()
        except:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в `try`/`except` – при выполнении кода происходило исключение, которое конструкцией игнорировалось что не позволило найти другие ошибки.

Код:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import (
    QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout, 
    QApplication, QMessageBox, QTextEdit
)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Example')

        self.pb_open_file = QPushButton('Open file...')
        self.pb_open_file.clicked.connect(self._on_open_file)

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_open_file)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def _on_open_file(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/')[0]
        if not file_name:
            return

        try:
            with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                data = f.read()
                self.text_edit.setText(data)

        except Exception as e:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(450, 670)
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: увы, но безрезультатно.

Comment: @Иван, а ну конечно -- у вас `self.textEdit` в том методе с диалогом, но в конструкторе просто `text` -- разные ведь виджеты

Comment: @Иван, если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте ответ :)